# FullCalendar and Variables - Json

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a HTML section that builds a variable containing this:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
var mevent = "{id: 1,title: 'Jan',start: '2016-07-10T10:45',end: '2016-07-10T11:15'},{id: 2,title: 'Gert',start: '2016-07-26T06:00',end: '2016-07-26T22:00'},{id: 7,title: 'Piet',start: '2016-07-10T08:00',end: '2016-07-10T09:00'}"
</script>
```

Then the java section, containing this:

```
<script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        return $('<div>' + event.title + '</div>');
    },
    events: [mevent]

});
//function event() {return mevent;}
//document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = event();
</script>
```

Using the getElementById displays the data correctly, but using it as variable inside the calendar shows nothing, unless pasted into the events section as displayed by using getElementById.

What would the syntax be to use the variable inside the calendar script?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, you put me on the right track...
This worked:

```
var newEvents = JSON.stringify(eval(mevent));
var allEvents = $.parseJSON(newEvents);
```

Comment: Eval is believed to be bad because it can execute any random JS code that happens to be in your json string.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse() to convert your string into an actual JS object:

```
events: JSON.parse(mevent)
```